# Term for words that are modified by prefixing the word with "a" (e.g. anew, aplenty)

Tags: meaning, etymology, modifiers

It occurred to me that there are quite a large number of words - many of them archaic - that are existing words prefixed with the letter 'a' to create a new word. For example: anew, aplenty, atwitter, apace, etc.

1) Is there a term for this particular modifier , or if not, what's the origin of the term (were these words formerly separate words - e.g. 'a new' - that later became one, thereby fossilising the 'phrase'?

2) Is there any way of working out a list of such words?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you're looking at this backwards, that this is a matter of *losing* a prefix to make a new word? Then the modifier becomes obsolete.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-

Comment: There are several different prefixes that have collapsed into "a-" along the course of English history. And there is no name for them, or any subset of them. It's just a prefix, like any other prefix, and doesn't deserve a special name for its words.

Comment: I'd suggest calling it the "aadverb" modifier and eventually we'd kick the aardvark out of first position in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @dotsamuelswan, you might want to check out [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-&allowed_in_frame=0) page on the prefix *a*-. See the first definition. It points out that there are a few different sources for the *a*- prefix. The linked page quotes the OED as follows:

> [I]t naturally happened that all these *a*- prefixes were at length
>   confusedly lumped together in idea, and the resultant *a*- looked upon
>   as vaguely intensive, rhetorical, euphonic, or even archaic, and
>   wholly otiose. [OED]